# Sort spanned words located on the same string

Tags: python, dataframe

I need your help) I have a task for creating dataframe for a better analyzing of the data, I'll add sample structure of it. The data contains spanned results from people(three emails in the data) and labels that they chose. I had to create a dataframe that will contain 'text' column and all existing labels as a column namae. As values this column names take spanned text and email of person under the corresponding label. I achieved this result by creating this code:

```
with open("/data/notebook_files/td_data.json", 'r') as j:
    data = json.loads(j.read())

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df_data = {"text": []}
label_emails = {}
text_set = set()

for item in data:
    annotations = item.get("annotations", [])
    for annotation in annotations:
        results = annotation.get("result", [])
        for result in results:
            text = result["value"]["text"]
            label = result["value"]["paragraphlabels"][0]
            email = annotation["completed_by"]["email"]
            text = text.strip()
            text_set.add(text)

            if label not in label_emails:
                label_emails[label] = {}

            if text not in label_emails[label]:
                label_emails[label][text] = [email]
            else:
                label_emails[label][text].append(email)

unique_texts = list(text_set)
df_data = {"text": unique_texts}

for label in label_emails:
    df_data[label] = [[] for _ in unique_texts]

for label in label_emails:
    for text, emails in label_emails[label].items():
        idx = unique_texts.index(text)
        df_data[label][idx] = emails

print(df_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```

It showed the result:

```
{'text': ['Hey', 'Hello', 'Hello,', 'Training', 'How', 'Pretty'], 'Small Talk': [['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']], 'Discovery': [[], [], [], [], [], ['name2.surname@workmail.com']], 'Logistics': [[], [], [], [], ['name3.surname@workmail.com'], []]}
```

And then I understood smth-people are spanning the same text DIFFERENTLY. Notice as it added 'Hello', 'Hello,' as two different results. What I need is to also look at the 'start' value provided in data and compare results if they are located on the same string, if they are ALMOST similar-add the first one to the data.Then add column 'string_num' with 'start' value.

Here is data snippet:

```
[
    {
        "id": 65160663,
        "agreement": 45.94031223364905,
        "predictions": [],
        "annotations": [
            {
                "id": 20849093,
                "created_username": "name1.surname@workmail.com, 10583",
                "created_ago": "1\u00a0month, 1\u00a0week",
                "completed_by": {
                    "id": 10583,
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                    "email": "name1.surname@workmail.com",
                    "initials": "n1s"
                },
                "last_annotation_history": 21249790,
                "reviews": null,
                "result": [
                    {
                        "id": "yOfAYoJp-i",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "0",
                            "text": "Training",
                            "start": "0",
                            "endOffset": 8,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0jrV1HWkNX",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "2",
                            "text": "Hello,",
                            "start": "2",
                            "endOffset": 6,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Jbc3OG5lpa",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "3",
                            "text": "How",
                            "start": "3",
                            "endOffset": 4,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "kv0_cHIzFW",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "4",
                            "text": "Pretty ",
                            "start": "4",
                            "endOffset": 7,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    }
                ],
                "was_cancelled": false,
                "ground_truth": false,
                "created_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.770830Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.770851Z",
                "draft_created_at": null,
                "lead_time": 1445.542,
                "import_id": 478456,
                "last_action": "imported",
                "task": 65160663,
                "project": 38864,
                "updated_by": null,
                "parent_prediction": null,
                "parent_annotation": null,
                "last_created_by": 5512,
                "comment_count": 0,
                "unresolved_comment_count": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 20849095,
                "created_username": "name2.surname@workmail.com, 9804",
                "created_ago": "1\u00a0month, 1\u00a0week",
                "completed_by": {
                    "id": 9804,
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                    "email": "name2.surname@workmail.com",
                    "initials": "n2s"
                },
                "last_annotation_history": 21249792,
                "reviews": null,
                "result": [
                    {
                        "id": "MQak6JhlS7",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "0",
                            "text": "Training",
                            "start": "0",
                            "endOffset": 8,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "AtggRvZexv",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "1",
                            "text": "Hey",
                            "start": "1",
                            "endOffset": 3,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "efThrWB5hE",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "2",
                            "text": "Hello",
                            "start": "2",
                            "endOffset": 5,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "PDfg-d7lvj",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "3",
                            "text": "How ",
                            "start": "3",
                            "endOffset": 4,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Sm1Gl8zVZK",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "4",
                            "text": "Pretty ",
                            "start": "4",
                            "endOffset": 7,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Discovery"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    }
                ],
                "was_cancelled": false,
                "ground_truth": false,
                "created_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.768474Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.768501Z",
                "draft_created_at": null,
                "lead_time": 914.968,
                "import_id": 478455,
                "last_action": "imported",
                "task": 65160663,
                "project": 38864,
                "updated_by": null,
                "parent_prediction": null,
                "parent_annotation": null,
                "last_created_by": 5512,
                "comment_count": 0,
                "unresolved_comment_count": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 20849094,
                "created_username": "name3.surname@workmail.com, 10582",
                "created_ago": "1\u00a0month, 1\u00a0week",
                "completed_by": {
                    "id": 10582,
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                    "email": "name3.surname@workmail.com",
                    "initials": "n3s"
                },
                "last_annotation_history": 21249791,
                "reviews": null,
                "result": [
                    {
                        "id": "YpMNWcELLN",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "0",
                            "text": "Training",
                            "start": "0",
                            "endOffset": 8,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "lGDFvBFaLb",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "1",
                            "text": "Hey",
                            "start": "1",
                            "endOffset": 3,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "uFjzjQD1Z9",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "2",
                            "text": "Hello",
                            "start": "2",
                            "endOffset": 5,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "h7kFPQNJFO",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "3",
                            "text": "How",
                            "start": "3",
                            "endOffset": 3,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Logistics"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3drdCXuRPM",
                        "type": "paragraphlabels",
                        "value": {
                            "end": "4",
                            "text": "Pretty ",
                            "start": "4",
                            "endOffset": 7,
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "paragraphlabels": [
                                "Small Talk"
                            ]
                        },
                        "origin": "manual",
                        "to_name": "transcription",
                        "from_name": "Modifiers"
                    }
                ],
                "was_cancelled": false,
                "ground_truth": false,
                "created_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.773161Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.773179Z",
                "draft_created_at": null,
                "lead_time": 601.87,
                "import_id": 478481,
                "last_action": "imported",
                "task": 65160663,
                "project": 38864,
                "updated_by": null,
                "parent_prediction": null,
                "parent_annotation": null,
                "last_created_by": 5512,
                "comment_count": 0,
                "unresolved_comment_count": 0
            }
        ],
        "drafts": [],
        "annotators": [
            {
                "user_id": 10583,
                "annotated": true,
                "review": null
            },
            {
                "user_id": 10582,
                "annotated": true,
                "review": null
            },
            {
                "user_id": 9804,
                "annotated": true,
                "review": null
            }
        ],
        "inner_id": 1,
        "cancelled_annotations": 0,
        "total_annotations": 3,
        "total_predictions": 0,
        "completed_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.773161Z",
        "annotations_results": "[{id:YpMNWcELLN, type:paragraphlabels, value:{end:0, text:Training, start:0, endOffset:8, startOffset:0, paragraphlabels:[Small Talk]}, origin:manual, to_name:transcription, from_name:Modifiers},{id:lGDFvBFaLb, type:paragraphlabels, value:{end:1, text:Hey, start:1, endOffset:3, startOffset:0, paragraphlabels:[Small Talk]}, origin:manual, to_name:transcription, from_name:Modifiers},{id:uFjzjQD1Z9, type:paragraphlabels, value:",
        "predictions_results": "",
        "predictions_score": null,
        "storage_filename": null,
        "annotations_ids": "20849093,20849094,20849095",
        "predictions_model_versions": "",
        "avg_lead_time": 987.46,
        "draft_exists": false,
        "updated_by": [],
        "reviewers": [],
        "comments": "",
        "comment_authors": [],
        "reviewed": false,
        "reviews_accepted": 0,
        "reviews_rejected": 0,
        "ground_truth": false,
        "data": {
            "text": "https://video",
            "video": "https://text"
        },
        "meta": {},
        "created_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.699533Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-08-17T16:57:38.699557Z",
        "is_labeled": true,
        "overlap": 3,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "unresolved_comment_count": 0,
        "last_comment_updated_at": null,
        "project": 38864
    }
]
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
{'string_num': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'text': ['Hey', 'Hello', 'Training', 'How', 'Pretty'], 'Small Talk': [['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']], 'Discovery': [[], [], [], [], ['name2.surname@workmail.com']], 'Logistics': [[], [], [], ['name3.surname@workmail.com'], []]}
```

Here I tried to rewrite the code like this:

```
with open("/data/notebook_files/td_data.json", 'r') as j:
    data = json.loads(j.read())

label_emails = {}
text_set = set()

for item in data:
    annotations = item.get("annotations", [])
    for annotation in annotations:
        results = annotation.get("result", [])
        for result in results:
            text = result["value"]["text"]
            label = result["value"]["paragraphlabels"][0]
            email = annotation["completed_by"]["email"]

            # Strip text to ensure uniqueness
            text = text.strip()

            if label not in label_emails:
                label_emails[label] = {}

            if text not in label_emails[label]:
                label_emails[label][text] = {"emails": [email]}
            else:
                label_emails[label][text]["emails"].append(email)

final_data = {"string_num": [], "text": []}
string_num = 0

# Iterate through the unique texts while maintaining the original order
for item in data:
    annotations = item.get("annotations", [])
    for annotation in annotations:
        results = annotation.get("result", [])
        for result in results:
            text = result["value"]["text"]
            label = result["value"]["paragraphlabels"][0]

            # Strip text to ensure uniqueness
            text = text.strip()

            # Check if the text is not already in the set
            if text not in text_set:
                text_set.add(text)
                final_data["string_num"].append(string_num)
                final_data["text"].append(text)
                string_num += 1

# Create dictionaries for each label and update the final_data dictionary
for label in label_emails:
    label_data = []
    for text in final_data["text"]:
        if text in label_emails[label]:
            label_data.append(list(set(label_emails[label][text]["emails"])))
        else:
            label_data.append([])

    final_data[label] = label_data

print(final_data)
```

But the output is not what I'm looking for:

```
{'string_num': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'text': ['Training', 'Hello,', 'How', 'Pretty', 'Hey', 'Hello'], 'Small Talk': [['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name1.surname@workmail.com'], ['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name1.surname@workmail.com'], ['name3.surname@workmail.com', 'name1.surname@workmail.com'], ['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com'], ['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']], 'Discovery': [[], [], [], ['name2.surname@workmail.com'], [], []], 'Logistics': [[], [], ['name3.surname@workmail.com'], [], [], []]}
```

Can you help me achieve this result?

```
string_num,text,Small Talk,Discovery,Logistics
0,Training,"['name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']",[],[]
1,Hey,"['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']",[],[]
2,Hello,"['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']",[],[]
3,How ,"['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name2.surname@workmail.com']",[],['name3.surname@workmail.com']
4,Pretty ,"['name1.surname@workmail.com', 'name3.surname@workmail.com']",['name2.surname@workmail.com'],[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to pivot the dataframe:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd

with open("your_data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

all_data = []
for d in data:
    for a in d["annotations"]:
        for r in a["result"]:
            all_data.append(
                {
                    "text": r["value"]["text"].strip(" ,"),
                    "email": a["completed_by"]["email"],
                    "paragraphlabels": r["value"]["paragraphlabels"],
                }
            )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).explode("paragraphlabels")
df = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index="text", columns="paragraphlabels", values="email", aggfunc=list
    )
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       text                     Discovery                     Logistics                                                                            Small Talk
0     Hello                           NaN                           NaN  [name1.surname@workmail.com, name2.surname@workmail.com, name3.surname@workmail.com]
1       Hey                           NaN                           NaN                              [name2.surname@workmail.com, name3.surname@workmail.com]
2       How                           NaN  [name3.surname@workmail.com]                              [name1.surname@workmail.com, name2.surname@workmail.com]
3    Pretty  [name2.surname@workmail.com]                           NaN                              [name1.surname@workmail.com, name3.surname@workmail.com]
4  Training                           NaN                           NaN  [name1.surname@workmail.com, name2.surname@workmail.com, name3.surname@workmail.com]
```